# Using stbi_write_png, how do you convert a rectangular byte-array of 0s and 1s to a monochrome png file?

Tags: c++, bitmap

Using the [stb image library](https://github.com/nothings/stb), how would one convert a rectangular array of bytes, each element having the value 0 or 1, to a single-color png image where the 1s represent colored pixels, using a call to the stbi_image_write function? This is the code we have so far:

```
using namespace std;

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb/stb_image.h"
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb/stb_image_write.h"

/* ... */

const uint32_t BITMAP_SIZE = height * width;
uint8_t* bitmap = new uint8_t[BITMAP_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < BITMAP_SIZE; i++) // clear the bitmap
    bitmap[0] = 0;
/* write 1s to some elements of bitmap */

constexpr int CHANNELS = 4; // indexed (really 1 or 0)
string filename = "my_image.png";
stbi_write_png(/* what parameters should be passed here? */); 
delete [] bitmap;
```

What would be the correct way to pass the parameters to stbi_write_png to get the desired output described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need CHANNELS=1 (because it's 1 byte per pixel).

```
stbi_write_png(filename.c_str(), width, height,
                             CHANNELS, bitmap, width * CHANNELS);
```